# Macro to generate an enum and an array of strings

Tags: c, enum, macros

Often when I find myself working with magic number enum values and I want to know what they represent, so I create an array of strings in order to print out their label.

This macro automates that process.

```
//#define DEBUG
#define GENERATE_ENUM(ENUM) ENUM,
#define GENERATE_STRING(STRING) #STRING,
#define GENERATE_ENUM_LIST(MACRO, NAME) \
   enum NAME                            \
   {                                    \
      MACRO(GENERATE_ENUM)              \
   };

//#ifdef DEBUG
#define GENERATE_ENUM_STRING_NAMES(MACRO, NAME) \
   const char *NAME##_Strings[] = {             \
       MACRO(GENERATE_STRING)                   \
   };

//#else
//#define GENERATE_ENUM_STRING_NAMES(MACRO, NAME)
//#endif
```

To use do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* ~ The macro ~ */

#define macro_handler(T) \
  T(ZERO) \
  T(ONE) \
  T(TWO)

GENERATE_ENUM_STRING_NAMES(macro_handler, nuclearLaunchCodesData)
GENERATE_ENUM_LIST(macro_handler, nuclearLaunchCodesData)
#undef macro_handler

int main() {
  printf("%s\n", nuclearLaunchCodesData_Strings[ZERO]);
}
```

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most macro solutions are not readable nor maintainable. You should avoid macro solutions like this.

The best way is to not use macros at all:

```
typedef enum
{
  ZERO,
  ONE, 
  TWO, 
  THREE,
  NUMBERS_N
} numbers_t;

static const char* NUMBER_STR[NUMBERS_N] = 
{
  [ZERO]  = "ZERO",
  [ONE]   = "ONE",
  [TWO]   = "TWO",
  [THREE] = "THREE",
};

puts(NUMBER_STR[1]); // prints ONE
```

This code is perfectly readable and it maintains the integrity between the enum and the array well. It only has one small problem and that is code repetition.

Code repetition should be avoided, but programmers tend to exaggerate how bad it is. It is rarely ever so bad that it justifies turning your whole program into "macro hell".

The reasons why code repetition should be avoided is that is leads to typo-like bugs and problems with maintenance. However, while a "macro hell" solution might rule out the typos, it makes the code difficult to maintain and the increased complexity increases the chance of other more serious bugs.

Famous quote by Brian Kernighan:

> Everyone knows that debugging is twice as hard as writing a program in the first place. So if you're as clever as you can be when you write it, how will you ever debug it?

That being said, there are valid cases where you must centralize data in one place, particularly when maintaining existing code that shouldn't be changed more than necessary. The macro you posted is a flavour of "[X macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro)", which is the preferable way to write such macros - "messy in a standardized way" so to speak. X macros is about defining a list of data as you do, but to pass on that data to localized macros embedded into the code itself. To rewrite the above code with X macros, you'd do:

```
#define NUMBER_LIST \
  X(ZERO)           \
  X(ONE)            \
  X(TWO)            \
  X(THREE)          \

typedef enum
{
  #define X(name) name,
    NUMBER_LIST
  #undef X
  NUMBERS_N
} numbers_t;

static const char* NUMBER_STR[NUMBERS_N] = 
{
  #define X(name) [name] = #name,
    NUMBER_LIST
  #undef X
};

puts(NUMBER_STR[1]); // prints ONE
```

The advantage here is the flexibility to apply the same data in different ways, on case-by-case basis. A macro such as `#define X(name) [name] = #name,` is cryptic by itself, but when given the context of the surrounding array initializer list, one can easier understand the meaning. "X macros" can also be used to manually unroll loops:

```
#define X(name) puts(NUMBER_STR[name]);
  NUMBER_LIST
#undef X
```

This is equivalent to iterating over the array and printing all items, but the loop is unrolled and we end up with a number of `puts` calls.

Comment: Using the C programming language there is no way to write generics except for macros.

Comment: @pacmaninbw There is _Generic but I'm not sure what that has to do with this post.

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep this in mind as I'm working on a rather large side project that requires this sort of thing (https://github.com/BoredBored/Turtle/blob/master/failed-attempts/attempt5/token.h). Additionally, my example does not work as I forgot to put `GENERATE_ENUM_LIST()` before I undef-ed `nuclearLaunchCodes`

Comment: @Lundin _Generic is a misnomer. It more of an overload selector and doesn't generate code. Macros do generate code but you have to specify the code.

Answer (score 4):

There's a variant style of creating X-Macros that I much prefer to the example presented by Lundin (in his otherwise excellent answer).

Rather than use the name `X` for the internal macro -- and having to `#define` and `#undef` it each time it's used -- you can give each *handler* macro a meaningful name and pass in the name of the handler to the *list* macro.

```
#define EACH_NUMBER(_) \
  _(ZERO) \
  _(ONE) \
  _(TWO) \
  _(THREE) \
/*end EACH_NUMBER */

#define AS_BARE_NAME_COMMA(TOKEN) TOKEN ,
#define AS_STRING_COMMA(TOKEN) #TOKEN ,

enum {
  EACH_NUMBER( AS_BARE_NAME_COMMA )
};
char *number_string[] = {
  EACH_NUMBER( AS_STRING_COMMA )
};

puts( number_string[ ONE ] );
```

Answer (score 1):

The other two current answers provide clean solutions, but they become trickier to implement if the `enum` tokens are to be known to multiple source files. And, there is often a need for more than merely *string-ising* the enum token names.

Rules are made to be broken.

Although it is generally a bad idea putting any data definition into a header file, if done rarely and with clear commenting, it can provide a clean solution. The strings can be refined to suit the need, and the tokens can be known to multiple *compilation units* (source files).

```
// map.h - Do NOT use Header Guards

#ifdef AS_STRING
#   define X( a, b ) b
    char *str[] = {
#else
    extern char *str[]; // facilitate 'global' access across compilation units
#   define X( a, b ) a
    enum {
#endif
    X( str_0, "nothing to see here" ),
    X( str_1, "this is one" ),
    X( str_2, "it takes two, baby" ),
    /* ... */
    X( str_done, NULL ),
};
#undef X
```

and

```
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>

#include "map.h" // enum now visible to this code

#define AS_STRING
#include "map.h" // str[] now visible to this code
#undef AS_STRING

// Shown here in main source file but could be in
// another source file that uses #include "map.h" alone
void func_in_other_src( void ) {
    puts( "Hi from other source file" );
    puts( str[ str_2 ] );
}

int main( void ) {
    for( size_t i = 0; str[ i ]; i++ ) // entire list
        puts( str[ i ] );
    puts( "" );

    func_in_other_src(); // go off somewhere else

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
nothing to see here
this is one
it takes two, baby

Hi from other source file
it takes two, baby
```

One could hide `str[]` (in this example) by declaring the array to be `static`, then providing a *helper function* for the use of a caller to retrieve a needed string from that *private* list.